# Why does the mobile sdk ask for login in emulator but not on desktop

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, hybrid

I'm developing a hybrid android app, and I'd like to test everything in a regular desktop browser first because the android emulator is incredibly slow in deploying. The problem is that in the emulator I am asked for identification when I build the first time, but when I just run the index.html in a browser, I am not. This leads to the forcetk client being undefined and all the problems that entails. Is there a way to include logging in to Salesforce in this type of local testing as well?

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this issue as well over the years. The SDK does NOT directly support testing your hybrid apps on the browser because the oAuth dance happens via a WebView that's triggered by Cordova specific APIs such as onDeviceReady which fire only on the phone (device/ emu). This is the reason why you typically get the forcetk undefined on your browser while it works on devices/ emulator as it's handled by Mobile SDK using Cordova under the hood.

Having mentioned that, I believe it should be possible to do so if you can modify the auth flow to manage forcetk instantiation in your custom code while bypassing the Mobile SDK oAuth dance - however that can be a bit complex.