# Testing Hybrid Remote app in web browser

Tags: mobile, hybrid, hybrid-remote

Is it possible to test a Hybrid Remote app in a web browser?

The documentation makes it seems as though I simply need to replace 'cordova.js' with 'mockcordova.js' and add 'mocksmartstore.js'. However when I try that, cordova's "DeviceReady" function does not get triggered and none of app's functionality works.

Anyone have details on how to get a Hybrid (Remote) app running in the browser?

*Mock files were pulled from the sample projects (https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/tree/master/samples/simplesyncreact/js)

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the question I answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/why-does-the-mobile-sdk-ask-for-login-in-emulator-but-not-on-desktop/34907#34907). If you are using Angular.js for your hybrid app, use forceng.js - it is very similar to forcetk.js (without jQuery) and is compatible with Mobile SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get browser testing working for the hybrid remote app, which uses Visual Force Remoting, by also including a few other JS files (not just mocksmartstore and mockcordova). The JS files are loaded like this:

$Resource.underscore

$Resource.mockcordova

$Resource.cordova_force

$Resource.mocksmartstore

$Resource.MY_APP_JS_FILE

MockCordova and MockSmartStore are available here: github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/tree/master/test

Underscore:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/dependencies/underscore/underscore-min.js

Corova Force:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/libs/cordova.force.js